# Deleting rows dynamically based on certain condition in R

Tags: r

**Problem description:**

From the below table, I would want to remove all the rows above the quarter value of 2014-Q3 i.e. rows 1,2
Also note that this is a dynamic data-set. Which means when we move on to the next quarter i.e. 2016-Q3, I would want to remove all the rows above quarter value of 2014-Q4 automatically through a code without any manual intervention
(and when we move to next qtr 2016-Q4, would want to remove all rows above 2015-Q1 and so on)

I have a variable which captures the first quarter I would like to see in my final data-frame (in this case 2014-Q3) and this variable would change as we progress in the future

```
          QTR                  Revenue
1       2014-Q1                 456
2       2014-Q2                 3113
3       2014-Q3                 23
4       2014-Q4                 173
5       2015-Q1                 1670
6       2015-Q2                 157
7       2015-Q3                 115
..        ..                    ..
10      2016-Q2                 232
```

How do I code this?

Comment: show an expected output and dput your df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks lmo
Was going through articles and I think we can use the dplyr package to do this in a much simpler way:

```
>df % slice((nrow(df)-7):(nrow(df)))
```

Get the below result

```
>df
3       2014-Q3                 23
4       2014-Q4                 173
5       2015-Q1                 1670
6       2015-Q2                 157
7       2015-Q3                 115
..        ..                    ..
10      2016-Q2                 232
```

This would act in a dynamic way too as once we have more rows entered beyond 2016-Q2, the range of 8 rows (to be selected) is maintained by the nrow function

Answer (score 0):

Here is a semi-automated method using `which`:

```
myFunc <- function(df, year, quarter) {
  dropper <- paste(year, paste0("Q",(quarter-1)), sep="-")
  df[-(1:which(as.character(df$QTR)==dropper)),]
}

myFunc(df, 2014, 3)
      QTR Revenue
3 2014-Q3      23
4 2014-Q4     173
5 2015-Q1    1670
6 2015-Q2     157
7 2015-Q3     115
```

To subset, you can just assign output

```
dfNew <- myFunc(df, 2014, 3)
```

At this point, you can pretty easily change the year and quarter to perform a new subset.